# std::result_of parameter type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've been having this question for some time. Suppose we have a contrived function:

```
template<typename F>
std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F>(???)> transform(F&& f)
{
    static const int num = 42;
    return std::forward<F>(f)(num);
}
```

The thing I'm not sure of is whether I should use `int` or `const int&` for the `???` part. Similarly, for this function:

```
template<typename F>
std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F>(???)> transform(F&& f)
{
    ExpensiveType foo;
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::move(foo));
}
```

Should I use `ExpensiveType` or `ExpensiveType&&` for the `???` part?

Comment: If you have C++14 why not use `auto`?

Comment: @NathanOliver My real use case requires that I can deduce the type as early as in the template parameter list, so essentially I need to get the type that `auto` deduces *before* the function signature...

Comment: Is `ExpensiveType` a template parameter as well ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It can be (and most of the time is). Is that going to make a difference?

Comment: @ZizhengTai yes, in some corner cases, when you don't know what `ExpensiveType` is, you may end up with different behavior. To avoid mismatch, use `auto transform(F&& f) -> decltype(std::declval<F&&>()(std::move(std::declval<ExpensiveType&>())))`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Can't I use `std::result_of_t<F&&(ExpensiveType&&)>`?

Comment: @ZizhengTai one corner case is that `ExpensiveType` is a reference type, then, `ExpensiveType& &&` collapses to `ExpensiveType&`, while `std::move` casts uncoditionally to an rvalue. There are more rare cases, that's why I said *"in some corner cases (...) if you want to avoid mismatch"*

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I see. If `T` is a non-reference type, can I safely use `std::result_of_t<F&&(T&&)>` (assuming I pass a `std::move`d argument to a callable `F&& f`)?

Comment: @ZizhengTai not if you want to correctly handle 100% cases instead of *only* 99,9%

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What else can go wrong in this case? (`T` is *not* a template parameter, just some non-ref type)

Comment: @ZizhengTai other cases are: `T` is an array, `T` is a function type, `T` is *cv*-qualified, and at the same time `F` has an overloaded `operator()`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki But since C++14 "F and all types in ArgTypes can be any complete type, array of unknown bound, or (cv-qualified) void". http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of

Comment: @ZizhengTai I didn't say they can't be, I said using such types with and without `&&` in `result_of` may lead to different results, but you really don't have to worry about that

Answer (score 2):

Use auto!

C++14:

```
template < typename F >
auto transform(F&& f)
{
    constexpr auto num = 42;
    return std::forward<F>(f)(num);
}
```

C++11:

```
template < typename F >
auto transform(F&& f) -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(42))
{
    // ... same body
}
```

Comment: Yes my example can indeed be converted this way, but the real situation is actually a bit more complicated. In short, the deduced type is a template parameter with default value (the result of `std::result_of`) but can also be specified by the user.